# How to customize the VS2015 Method Signature Pop-Up's Text Color?

Tags: themes, customization, visual-studio-2015

I've started using Visual Studio 2015 and one thing I've noticed is the new fancy rich-text formatted Preview functionality when hovering over a Method, .ctor, Property etc (compared to the bare tooltip I see in VS2013), which looks for example like this (mouse cursor is not shown here):

[image]

However, this is, most likely due to my general text color & font customization, in parts barely readable.

Does anyone know what's the correct name and category for this enhanced ToolTip is in VS's Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip code colors correspond to the colors you have set for the editor window. The white you see is the same as you see in the editor.

You might want to [change the tooltip background color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31809128/104707) instead to something darker.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the 'Editor Tooltip'

Use these steps:
Options -> Environment -> Fonts & Colors

Show settings for: Editor Tooltip

Adjust 'Plain Text'

Comment: Thanks for your answer @thllbrg ! However that does not entirely work / provide what I was looking for. The screenshot shows that this ToolTip colorizes the different parts of the information shown, particularly that last part seems to have a 'white' or near white forecolor.. but the Editor ToolTip > Plain Text part is already set to Black.. and that Editor ToolTip category only has a Plain Text Section. So it is not quite what I was looking for :-/

Comment: To bad, then I think your best bet is to go with Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor [link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b) Good luck! @JörgB.