# Change tooltip background color in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In VS2015 I have the Color Theme Editor extension installed and I'm using the Dark with Light Editor theme.

The hover tooltips are mostly unreadable as the tooltip background is too dark.

[image: screenshot]

I've tried changing settings in Tools → Options → Environment → Fonts and Colors, but couldn't find anything to make the signature just plain white.  I've also tried cloning the theme through the theme editor and customizing the settings, but I don't know what settings would be responsible for this.

Does anyone know how to make this readable?

Comment: The setting you are looking for should be in Editor tooltip, but MS didn't expose it for some reason and for now you can only change the plain text in the tooltip.

Comment: @thllbrg I found that setting, and I changed the foreground text, but it only changed the comment text that sometimes appears at the bottom of a tooltip. Hovering over an HTML tag shows that dark background with black text for the description, so I'm not sure what that color is bound to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the Color Theme Editor extension, change the tooltip background color like this:

1. Click on "Edit Theme"
2. Click on "Show All Elements" in the menu bar (by default, only "Common Elements" are shown)
3. Find the `Environment -> ToolTip` entry. This affects the tooltip background color.

Comment: Well... don't I feel stupid. I thought I had tried this and it didn't work. Guess I just didn't do it right. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Brandon: When it comes to Visual Studio's Fonts and Colors / Themes train wreck, nobody should ever feel stupid.

Comment: Is there any way to do this where it doesn't blow out all my existing fonts and colors?

Comment: Nvm, there is an "Import Font / Color Customizations" button on the right side of the Edit window's toolbar that does what I want.

Answer (score 19):

You can change the tooltip background color like this (does not require *Color Theme Editor* extension):

1. Tools > Options...
2. Environment > Fonts and Colors
3. *Show settings for:* Environment
4. *Display items:* ToolTip
5. Select color from *Item background* dropdown or click *Custom* button

[image: Look of Options dialog with selected ToolTip item]

Comment: This is quick and clean

Answer (score 1):

This is a fix for users using Windows High Contrast Theme. 
In such case there is no way to change tooltip background color in Visual Studio options window and neither in Theme Color Editor extension.
 So to fix it:

1. Go to /AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Themes and find theme you are currently using.
2. Open it in editor and find section [Control Panel\Colors]
3. Modify properties InfoText and InfoWindow  for example

   - InfoText=255 255 255
   - InfoWindow=0 0 0
4. Reload current theme (switch to other theme and then back to this)

Result (Visual Studio 2015 and Windows High Contrast theme):

[image: Final result]A

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Color Theme Editor Extension with the custom theme, based on "Dark with light editor".
Actually, the background color of the tooltip for me was 

Environment -> CommandBarMenuBackgroundGradientBegin.

 (see Brandon's answer on how to change it)

 [IDE Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK34x.jpg)