# How to change the background color in visual studio 2015 of the method definition popup

Tags: visual-studio

When writing code and calling a method visual studio will pop up a tooltip window with the xml metadata describing the parameters.  Does anyone know how to change the background color of that tooltip (if indeed it is called a tooltip).[image]

I imported a theme I really like and I'm modifying a few things that are hard to read, this is one of them.  I haven't found it yet, obviously...

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729553/change-tooltip-background-color-in-vs2015/31809128#31809128) seems to have an answer.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I was able to used that tool then Import my other settings and the tooltip stayed the new color.